openpyxl is not able to understand my 2 sub header
I have an Excel sheet with data:

when I try to create a chart like this [clustered chart]

openpyxl is not able to read the data properly
from openpyxl.chart import BarChart, Reference
from openpyxl import load_workbook, workbook

wb = load_workbook("Book1.xlsx")
ws = wb.active
data = Reference(ws, min_col=2, min_row=1, max_row=12,max_col=7)
categories = Reference(ws, min_col=1, min_row=3, max_row=12)

barChart = BarChart()

barChart.type = "col"
barChart.grouping = "clustered"
barChart.title = "XYZ"
barChart.y_axis.title = "service"
barChart.x_axis.title = "month"

barChart.add_data(data,titles_from_data=True)
barChart.set_categories(categories,labels="dasd")

barChart.style = 5
barChart.width = 20
barChart.height = 10

ws.add_chart(barChart,"k8")

wb.save("test.xlsx")

I tried to unmerge the headers, but again, if I do that, the graph I want will not be created.
I tried all the combinations but it's just openpyxl don't capture the data properly

You can add each row as a separate Series.
For each row m2 to m10 add as a Series after the initial data row m1 is added.
The categories which contains the two level Header is taken from the Rows 1 & 2. Then enable 'Multi-Level Category Labels' for the X Axis.
The code sample below assumes your data is contained in the range A1:G12,
Code Sample I
from openpyxl.chart import (
    BarChart,
    Reference,
    Series
)
from openpyxl import load_workbook
from openpyxl.chart.layout import Layout, ManualLayout

wb = load_workbook("book1.xlsx")
ws = wb.active

### Chart Type
barChart = BarChart()

### Initial data Series m1 B3:G3
data = Reference(ws, min_col=1, min_row=3, max_row=3, max_col=7)
barChart.add_data(data, titles_from_data=True, from_rows=True)

### Data Categories (B1:G2), 2 sub header
categories = Reference(ws, min_col=2, max_col=7, min_row=1, max_row=2)
### Add Categories to Chart
barChart.set_categories(categories)
### Set X Axis multilevel label to enabled
barChart.x_axis.noMultiLvlLbl = False

### Add additional Series m2 - m10
### Create a Series for each row from m2 (row 4) to m10 (row 12)
for i in range(4, 13):  # 13 is ws.max_row+1
    data = Reference(ws, min_col=1, min_row=i, max_col=7, max_row=i)
    ### Use the header in Column A as the title
    series = Series(data, title_from_data=True)
    ### Add the created Series to the chart
    barChart.append(series)


### Chart Settings
barChart.type = "col"
barChart.grouping = "clustered"
barChart.title = "XYZ"
barChart.y_axis.title = "service"
barChart.x_axis.title = "month"

# barChart.style = 5  # Use Chart Style required. This example leaves as default
barChart.width = 20
barChart.height = 10

### Additional Chart Settings
### Set the 'Series Overlap', gap between columns 
barChart.overlap = -10  # -10 is -10% 

# Enable Axis for display
barChart.x_axis.delete = False
barChart.y_axis.delete = False

### Set the legend position at the bottom of the chart
barChart.legend.position = "b"

### Adjust the layout to ensure enough space for the legends at the bottom of the chart
barChart.layout = Layout(
    manualLayout=ManualLayout(
        x=0,  # x position of the plot area
        y=0,  # y position of the plot area
        h=0.65,  # height of the plot area
        w=0.9,  # width of the plot area
    )
)

### Add Chart to Sheet
ws.add_chart(barChart, "K8")

### Save workbook
wb.save('test.xlsx')

Code Sample II
Add all Series as one data reference
from openpyxl.chart import (
    BarChart,
    Reference
)
from openpyxl import load_workbook
from openpyxl.chart.layout import Layout, ManualLayout

wb = load_workbook("book1.xlsx")
ws = wb.active

### Chart Type
barChart = BarChart()

### Initial data Series' B3:G12
data = Reference(ws, min_col=1, min_row=3, max_row=12, max_col=7)
barChart.add_data(data, titles_from_data=True, from_rows=True)

### Data Categories (B1:G2), 2 sub header
categories = Reference(ws, min_col=2, max_col=7, min_row=1, max_row=2)
### Add Categories to Chart
barChart.set_categories(categories)
### Set X Axis multilevel label to enabled
barChart.x_axis.noMultiLvlLbl = False

### Chart Settings
barChart.type = "col"
barChart.grouping = "clustered"
barChart.title = "XYZ"
barChart.y_axis.title = "service"
barChart.x_axis.title = "month"

# barChart.style = 5  # Use Chart Style required. This example leaves as default
barChart.width = 20
barChart.height = 10

### Additional Chart Settings
### Set the 'Series Overlap', gap between columns
barChart.overlap = -10  # -10 is -10%

# Enable Axis for display
barChart.x_axis.delete = False
barChart.y_axis.delete = False

### Set the legend position at the bottom of the chart
barChart.legend.position = "b"

### Adjust the layout to ensure enough space for the legends at the bottom of the chart
barChart.layout = Layout(
    manualLayout=ManualLayout(
        x=0,  # x position of the plot area
        y=0,  # y position of the plot area
        h=0.65,  # height of the plot area
        w=0.9,  # width of the plot area
    )
)

### Add Chart to Sheet
ws.add_chart(barChart, "K8")

### Save workbook
wb.save('test.xlsx')

The following is the expected Chart produced.


Thank you so much. I didn't know about the series one.

@Aman Chourasiya,  Actually I had made an error on my first code test that I didn't immediately determine so had changed the code to add the series separately. Your original method without  adding Series separately would also work. I've fixed and updated the answer with that method as a 2nd code sample. Either method would result in the same chart.
